# Cart Price Rules does not work on a Configurable Simple Products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I am trying to create a promotion code, **17% off selected products with minimum spending of $30.**

the selected products eligible for this promotion code are

1. SKU1 (parent configurable product a)
2. SKU1-1, SKU1-2, SKU 1-3, SKU 1-4 (4 out of 4 child product of configurable parent product a)
3. SKU 2 (parent configurable product b)
4. SKU 2-1, SKU 2-2, SKU 2-3 (3 out of 5 child product of configurable parent product b)

under the "conditions", here is what i did:

[image]

Category 36 consist of the aforementioned SKUs.

### Problem:

When the discount code was applied, the balance 2/5 child product 
(of configurable parent product b) that are not included in Category 
36 got discounted as well.

How do i get the promotion code to take effect without the two child products of configurable parent product b being included?

I have tried to exclude configurable parent product b in Category 36, but the code would then fail to apply in the checkout page.

I have also tried to include the product specific SKUs (in both Actions and Conditions) instead of the Category. But it doesnt seem to work as well.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Please explain the configuration of your products in a bit more detail, it's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. An example would also help: when exactly do you expect the discount to be applied?

Comment: @user57058 seems like you are using magento 2 , in magento 1 this was bug or it works like that only, may be some some extensions may help you......

Comment: it seems that in cart price rules, the configurable child sku is not recognised. after removing the parent configurable product in Category, the promotion code failed to apply. 

how can i make the configurable child product SKU readable in order for my discount to work? is that how my problem will be solved?

Comment: I tried creating a new configurable product and added products that are eligible for the discount into it. 

i then added this new configurable product into Category 36 to tie in with the discount. But it does not work too.